# Exibir imagem recebida via socket na tag img

Tags: javascript, html

Estou recebendo imagens de um servidor e preciso exibir a imagem na página html.As imagens são recebidas via socket, então tenho apenas o conteúdo da imagem.
A tag img exibe uma imagem quando há o src, neste caso seria necessário salvar a imagem no lado do cliente para depois exibir?
Agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Em qual formato a imagem é recebida, base64?

Comment: Não tenho certeza de qual formato. Uso uma biblioteca para extrair a imagem de um vídeo mjpeg no servidor e enviá-la ao cliente.

Comment: Se for base64, essa resposta pode te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169877/32827

Comment: @LucasCosta obrigado pela ajuda. Para funcionar eu precisei fazer apenas isso:
var b64Response = btoa(image);
document.querySelector("#myImage").src ='data:image/jpeg;base64,'+b64Response;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784145/display-image-from-http-response-with-image-content-type

Comment: Legal @BrunoClementino, responda sua pergunta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução com base nestes links:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169877/32827  sugerido por @LucasCosta e 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784145/display-image-from-http-response-with-image-content-type

Precisei converter a imagem recebida `var b64Response = btoa(image);`
e por fim atribuir a img.src dessa forma: `document.querySelector("#myImage").src ='data:image/jpeg;base64,'+b64Response;`